# TypeError 'index' is declared but its value is never read TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax-error

I'm currently making a chatbot for a school project. Its goal is to solve problems around school. But there are some issues in my code.                                                                           I keep getting the following message:

```
(parameter) index: any
'index' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
```

And...

```
TypeError: digibord is not a function
    at digibord.forEach (C:\Users\marti\Chatbot\index.js:47:13)
```

My code looks like the following:

```
var digibord =
    {
        name: ["digibord","smartboard","schoolbord"]
    };

function handleMessage(message) {
    digibord.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (value.name.includes(message)) {
            digibord();
            console.log(message);
        }
    });
}

function digibord() {
    const params = {
        icon_emoji: ':smiley:'
    }
    bot.postMessageToChannel('general', 'Okay...In what classroom is your current problem?',params);
};
```

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Well, when you read the errors what do they tell you?

Comment: You have a variable and a function called with the same name `digibord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is just a warning its not being used.

The second one, you have named a function and a variable the same name which you cannot do. Change the name of the variable or function